# How to retrieve the entire va_list input

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am familiar with va_arg list. I wanted to know is there a way through which we could fetch the value after comma

Eg

```
abc("%d %d %d how are you",1,2,3);
```

i want to know if it is possible to pass this entire call to a string without any processing like

```
string [1]="%d %d %d how are you",1,2,3;
```

I dont want to do any kind of processing , i simply want to read the entire call and store it in a string of array.

Comment: Hmm maybe check vsnprintf. I think there is an example like what you want to do inside the page I link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx

Comment: @Lefteris i dont want to output any data i simply want to store it entirely as i want to process it in later stages

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, do you mean you want to end up with a single string whose content is `"%d %d %d how are you",1,2,3` ? Or do you want an array of strings `"%d %d %d how are you"`, `"1"`, etc. ?  Those things are possible since C++11.

Answer (score 2):

As best I can understand your requirement, it is not possible in Standard C++03.  The most closely related C++ functionality is preprocessor macro argument stringification, which would allow something like this:

```
#define ABC(X) do { remember_string_version(#X); abc X; } while (false)

ABC(("%d %d %d how are you",1,2,3));
```

Note the double parenthesis - these group the string and numbers so they match the a single parameter "X" expected by ABC.

Preprocessor stringification is the *only* facility that lets you preserve some snippet of source code as a string, while still using it as source code....

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wanted to save the source code strings, I believe the OP wanted to "remember" the parameters without processing them at run time.

Comment: hmmm i think that should solve my purpose because i just need to fetch the entire string and then later on process.Thanks for the answer lemme try it and make it work :)

Comment: @Tony Delroy  
do { remember_string_version(#X); abc X; } while (false) //how to use this line of code

Comment: @hardyz009: where you call `ABC((...))`, the preprocessor will substitute `do { remember_string_version("(...)"); abc(...); } while (false)`.  You need to replace `remember_string_version()` with whatever you want to do with the source code string, and implement the abc function.  You haven't told us what you're really trying to achieve, so it's hard to offer more advice....

Comment: @littleadv: 'to "remember" the parameters without processing them at run time' - I can't even begin to make sense of that!  But, not saying you're wrong - the poster's obviously very new to the language and may want just about anything....

Comment: @TonyDelroy i want to just store "%d %d %d how are you",1,2,3 in a string array nothing else

Comment: @hardyz009: that might seem simple, but it's not clear.  "%d %d %d how are you" is a string - but 1, 2 and 3 are not strings.  Do you want an array containing [ "%d %d %d how are you", "1", "2", "3" ], or [ "\"%d %d %d how are you\"", "1", "2", "3" ], or a single-element array [ "\"%d %d %d how are you\", 1, 2, 3" ] to which you'd add other format/argument values?

Comment: @TonyDelroy i want it as a single array element [ "\"%d %d %d how are you\", 1, 2, 3" ].Then later on i will process this element using va_arg

Comment: i changed your code and used it like

#define abc(X) {z=X;}
main()
{
string z;
abc("%d %d %d how are you",1,2,3);
cout<<z;
}

Comment: @haryz009: that won't work - there's no way to break out a string back into separate items of data using va_arg....  And your macro is very strange... the point of using a #define macro is that it can be used in multiple places in the program, but there can be only one `main()`.  Also, your macro tries to call itself - it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is compiler dependent and while theoretically you can do that, in practice it is likely not to be portable. You can do it at a compile time through macros, as @Tony mentioned, but for run-time - use the `va_arg`. It basically implements what you want, and is a tool provided by the standard to interface to this compiler-dependent functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17 you can capture all the arguments and forward them to a stringstream in a single expression (called a *fold-expression*):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::string abc(auto&& head, auto&&... tail)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << head;
    ((out << ',' << tail), ...);

    return out.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = abc("%d %d %d how are you", 1, 2, 3);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Prior to C++17, but since C++11, you could use a recursive template (or the void braced list hack which I won't go into here).  Snippet:

```
template<typename Head>
void capture(std::ostream& out, Head&& head)
{
    out << std::forward<Head>(head);
}

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
void capture(std::ostream& out, Head&& head, Tail&&... tail)
{
    out << std::forward<Head>(head) << ',';
    capture(out, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}

template<typename... Args>
std::string abc(Args&&... args)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    capture(out, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    return out.str();    
}
```